# How back button is working in the browser?

Tags: php

I have listed projects in main work page, If i click on the project it will direct to work page  where details have been displayed,If i click on the back button its is redirecting main work page.I want back button should  redirect the previous project please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your back button to redirect you to the previous project, you need to change the present HTML from

```
 <a href="mainWork.php">BACK</a>
```

to :

```
 <a href="work.php?page=1">BACK</a>
```

You will have to do this dynamically by calculating the page numbers in the href  as $_GET['page'] - 1

```
 <? $page = (int) $_GET['page']; $back = $_GET['page'] - 1;
         print '<a href="work.php?page=$back">BACK</a>';
  ?>
```

Comment: Sorry.my question is not that.in my work [Link]( http://yellowandred.in/work.php?page=2) there is back button if i click back button in my page it should redirect to previous page like browser back

Comment: Just edit your question to mention this. I will edit my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

The back button in my browser is working as-designed on your site: it takes me to the previous webpage I was on.

Websites cannot (easily) alter the behaviour of the browser back button in order to keep the user in-control. You can't (easily) use the back button to navigate through a website (if I understand your question correctly).

Answer (score 0):

why not change the back button client-side?

```
<a href='#' id='backBtn'>Back</a>
```

And in JS:

```
document.getElementById('backBtn').onclick = function()
{
    history.back();
};
```

If all you want is for the back btn to behave like the browser back button?